# Excel-VBA transfer font format between cells through string concat

Tags: excel, vba

So I have several columns of numbers, its variable so lets say 3 just for example

```
Column B  Column C   Column D
**520**   600        **550**
```

Based on other processes, lets say column A and Column C are bolded.  I want to concatenate them into one cell and keep the bold formatting, like this:

```
Column A
**520**,600,**550**
```

and this will be repeated over a variable number of rows, some columns having two bold, some one bold, some having none.

Anyone have an easy way to get the bold formatting to follow?  I get the string to cat and write to the new cell, but I dont know how to get the format to the new concatenated cell.  The below code is just the inner loop and i use 2 for a single row instead of a variable for simplicity sake.

Heres what I have for the inner loop and the bold does not carry through:

```
Sub OneCell()

Dim i as Integer         'column number
Dim str1 as String       'String storage

i = 2                    'initialize col num
str1 = Cells(2, i).value 'initialize str1

'Outer loop
Do
    '....code for outer loop iterating rows

    'Inner loop to concatenate values into one string
    Do
        str1 = str1 & "," & Cells(2,i+1).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop until Cells(2,i+1).Value = ""

    'Put concatenated string in cell(2,1)
    Cells(2,1).Value = str1

Loop Until 'some condition of rows is met

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you'd have to use the Characters property and keep a record of what is bold as you go (in an array for example), put the text in the cell, and then go through the array to bold the relevant bits.

Comment: Hey thanks.  Oddly enough, I already have these numbers stored as properties in an array of custom objects (there are actually two additional properties associated with each of these values)...ill look into it.

Comment: Im also missing how the first cell if bolded gets carried over.  Say cell B2 is bold, the logic starts with cell C2 and is skipped, yet if i adjust the initialization value of i to 1, it sets the logic to start at cell B2 but then inserts a comma before it in str1...so then i reinsert a MID function prior to bolsing and then the first character of the first cell when carried over doesnt bold.  Ill mess with it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only posting this because I started a while ago and then got sidetracked.

```
Sub OneCell()

Dim i As Integer         'column number
Dim str1 As String       'String storage
Dim v(1 To 100, 1 To 3)  'the 100 limit is arbitrary
Dim j As Long

i = 2                    'initialize col num
str1 = Cells(2, i).Value 'initialize str1

Do
    If Cells(2, i + 1).Font.Bold Then
        j = j + 1
        v(j, 1) = 1
        v(j, 2) = Len(str1) + 2
        v(j, 3) = Len(Cells(2, i + 1))
    Else
        j = j + 1
        v(j, 1) = 0
    End If
    str1 = str1 & "," & Cells(2, i + 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop Until Cells(2, i + 1).Value = ""

With Cells(2, 1)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .font.bold=false
    .Value = str1
End With

For i = 1 To j
    If v(i, 1) = 1 Then
         Range("A2").Characters(v(i, 2), v(i, 3)).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Dang.  Lots of options.

Comment: I tried to accept both answers because it looks lile both are valid solutions but it only let me check thebforst one.

Comment: Never seen a variable declared that way and cant find anything on it.  What is it?  A range?  What does the syntax mean?

Comment: Dim v(1-100, 1 to 3)

Comment: Oh...its an array.  I was not seeing that with the 1-100 and 1 to 3

Comment: So....the first time I tied this it worked.  Every time after that, it cut off the first character and bolded everything rather than those that needed bolding.  Ill see if I can figure it out and sub an edit.

Comment: I've made one small amendment above - try that. One thing I noticed is that you are setting str1 to the value of cells(2,i) at the beginning and I wondered what was in that cell?

Comment: Theyre numbers.  Mostly integers between 6 and 40.  Sometimes theyll be floating point but only ever one decimal space, say like 9.3 or 33.1

Comment: It doesnt matter what type they are though as no calculations will be donenwith them.  Theyre just identifiers.  There are other properties that go with them that calculations are don on...which is actually where the bolding comes from.

Comment: I've made a couple of other small changes - let me know how you get on.

Comment: Its actually quite a bit trickier than just this, and I still have a lot to learn.  Its a very small portion of what I have.  I think this is probably the best solution to my problem.  Once i get this to work ill have to integrate it.  Ill pm you a copy of all of it if youre interested.  Dont want to post it all.  Does stackexchange have a pm?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is actually part of my only other vba post.  Pairwise comparison/division...

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a bit trickier than I thought, but i did find a way to get it to work (in other words, I tested the code). There may be a more efficient way, but this method works against a 3 cell range selection. You'll need to modify the range to fit into your program.

```
Sub ConcatWithBold()

Dim str1 As String

'first build string and identify bolded cells with *
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection

    If c.Font.Bold = True Then

        str1 = str1 & "," & "*" & c.Value

    Else

        str1 = str1 & "," & c.Value

    End If

Next

str1 = Mid(str1, 2) 'to remove first comma

Dim iCnt As Integer
For iCnt = 1 To Len(str1)

    If Mid(str1, iCnt, 1) = "*" Then

        'it's a bolded cell so make next 3 characters bold
        With Selection.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1)
            .Characters(iCnt, 3).Caption = Mid(str1, iCnt + 1, 3) 'set characters (add 1 to iCnt to skip asterik marking bold)
            .Characters(iCnt - 1, 3).Font.Bold = True 'make bold (-1 to include first character)
            iCnt = iCnt + 3 'jump to next comma
        End With

    Else

        With Selection.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1)
            .Characters(iCnt, 1).Caption = Mid(str1, iCnt, 1)
            .Characters(iCnt - 1, 1).Font.Bold = False '(-1 to include character just set
        End With

    End If


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  Ill try this too

Comment: I actually figured there was probably a better way to do it with a Range object but for some reason, I found it easier to creat my own object.  The Range object never works right for me...or at least the way I understand it.

Comment: I gave you an uptick but i havent been on long enough for it to count.  Soon, then ill come back.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. Best in integrating the code. If it works you can also mark as answered by pressing check mark.

Answer (score 0):

So my comments arent appearing anymore beneath your answer, @SJR.  So ill add here (i know im not supposed to but it seems to be all thats working at the moment, i apologize).  I got it to work with a little tweaking.

Initialize i to 1 at the beginning (the bolding is shifted if you dont)

Then add back in a Mid property before the With block statements
str1=Mid(str1,2)

I did this because i was finding if the first cell was bold it wouldnt bold the first set of characters (but it doea now).  Now ive run into another problem.  I need to be able to set the whole thing in a loop over a variable range because this is going to happen anywhere from 5-15 times depending on how many rows I have.  I tried using the cells property as a range reference which ive always gotten to work before but for some reason its giving a "method range of object_global failed" error on that line...and sometimes not but it will still fail to bold the string appropriately.